# Passing values from fla to AS3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

Can i passing values from fla to AS3. Example i have fla file where the xml faile loaded. No i want to make button "Button 1" and "Button 2" noh if i press the button it sent to AS3 values/variables

```
private var xmlURL:String = "xml/Button1.xml";
```

After buttone 2 is pressed  is

```
   private var xmlURL:String = "xml/Button2.xml";
```

How can i do this?

Best Regards,
a

Comment: Its kind of hard to understand what your asking, can you be clearer?

Answer (score 0):

If i understood you right, which i doubt i did. You want to change the value of the variable depending on which button was pressed, right? If that is the case, do the following:

Initialize the variable like so:
`private var xmlURL:String = "xml/Button1.xml";`

Next you should add an event listener for each button you have, like so: `Button1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, button1_handle);
Button2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, button2_handle);`

And then create the functions:
`function button1_handle(e:MouseEvent):void
{
   xmlURL = "xml/Button1.xml";
}

function button2_handle(e:MouseEvent):void
{
   xmlURL = "xml/Button2.xml";
}`